# How do certain badges on shields.io avoid using base-64 in their url

Tags: github, badge, readme, shields.io

I'm attempting to create a badge using shields.io for a GitHub project I'm involved in.  [Shields.io](http://shields.io) allows you to add your logo with base-64 encoding.  Pretty cool, however it's pretty unwieldy to place into your readme.  Given that I want to make it convenient for associated projects to paste our badge into their project, I don't want the markdown to be ten lines long.

I've noticed that not everyone has this problem.  Gitter, for example has a [very simple url](https://img.shields.io/gitter/room/nwjs/nw.js.svg) for its shield that contains a logo.

Bithound also has a [very nice badge url.](https://img.shields.io/bithound/code/github/rexxars/sse-channel.svg)

Are these special deals that they've worked out with [Shields.io](http://shields.io)?  Or is this sort of slickness available to everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shields.io has default support for a number of vendors displayed on the front page. Some of those custom integrations rely on corresponding logos: https://github.com/badges/shields/tree/master/logo.

I understand how having a large URL can be inconvenient. However, referencing external resources in images can yield unfortunate results, and is therefore disallowed (as does [GitHub](https://github.com/atmos/camo/blob/e6e9f047674f418a24034c68a80babce83573224/server.coffee#L43), which has had its share of sneaky DDoSes in the past years).

However, I believe using a URL shortener like bit.ly or goo.gl can help you have small URLs in your project files.